# Extremely simple docker compose reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, docker

We have many services that run on a server as a docker compose setup and which get deployed together with many other services outside that docker compose setup at https://myurl/myservice. Each of those many services has a different internal and external port, which makes it very confusing to develop because one has to constantly remember all those ports, so I want to add a reverse proxy for local development only. I tried out Traefik but it is much too heavyweight for my task and I could not get it to work with subfolder mapping, so I am looking for a docker container something similar to Traefik but very lightweight and extremely basic.
This is how the docker-compose.yml should look at the end:

```
services:

  service1:
    build: ./service1
    environment:
     - PROXY="/service1:8080"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8080:8890"
      - "127.0.0.1:1111:1111"
 [...]
  service99:
    build: ./service99
    environment:
     - PROXY="/service1:4567/internalpath"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4567:1234"

  simpleproxy:
    image: simpleproxy:latest
    profiles: ["dev"]
```